# Two way communication using TCP Client only

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

When dealing with TCP Client, especially when the stream has to be encrypted, the message will not be passed unless the `CryptoCtream` is closed and this results in the inner stream to be not readable as it will be disposed.

For instance

```
TCPClient client = new TCPClient("some ip", 1234);
using(var i = new CryptoStream(client.GetStream(), myEncryptor(),  CryptoStreamMode.Write) {
  i.Write(some Data, 0, 1024);
}
```

I've tried the flush but it seems that the data can be communicated only FROM the client to server this way. Being aware of all the alternatives, I'm curious about how this could be made possible (sending data using TCP Client and receiving a response even without setting a second channel).

Comment: well you have to write some code to read from the client stream

Comment: @pm100: yeah so smart, don't you see that the stream will be closed by that time and while it is open nothing is sent as I explained. !!!

Comment: Normally people don't use `CryptoStream` for two way network streams, you would normally use `SslStream` instead to provide a encrypted connection over a network stream..

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: SslStream is out of question for this case, you know that SSL costs :D

Comment: No, SSL cost money if you use a Public CA. However if you control both sides of the endpoint just use an embedded certificate in the program you created using [makecert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa386968(v=vs.85).aspx) for free. You only need a public CA if you don't have any pre-established way to send keying information to both sides. But you do have a way, the installer of your program!

Comment: In fact private CA's can be more secure than just using a public certificate because you can make your program only accept certificates signed by your private CA, now any [SSL Proxies](https://www.bluecoat.com/products-and-solutions/encrypted-traffic-management) that get in between the two endpoints can't decrypt the connection then re-encrpyt it with their own trusted certificate because the certificate will no longer be signed by your private CA.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I get your point and you are right, but the problem is that your solution (although very good and standard) is too much for what I'm doing. I think I use WCF instead and will make use of some built in security features instead.

Answer (score -2):

use an intermediate MemoryStream

```
var memstr = new MemoryStream();
using (var i = new CryptoStream(memstr.....)
{
   i.Write(some data);
   var buf = memstr.GetBuffer();
   client.GetStream().Write(buf);
}
var inp = client.GetStream.Read(..);
var memstr2 = new MemoryStream(inp);
using (var o = new CryptoStream(memstr2,...))
{
   var x = memstr2.Read();
}
```

Comment: seems like you didn't even understand the question!!

Comment: i understand the question. Why doesnt my answer work - I admit to not trying it out but I have done similar things many times.I agree I was unhelpfully flipant in my first comment

Comment: @If you even take a glance at your code you see that the stream is disposed already the second `Using` block!! and do you really expect that to even work ?? I'm curious to see how it could be possibly working!!

Comment: why do you think the tcp stream is closed when u close cryptostream, the docs says closing the cryptostream flushes (not closes) the underlying stream. If it does close it then use an intermediate MemoryStream, read from Tcp stream into byte array, create memorystream on byte array

Comment: @pm100 [He is correct](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/cryptography/cryptostream.cs,3bb570e73c03705d,references) that calling `CryptoStream.Dispose()` will cause the underlying stream to have `.Close()` called on it.

Comment: K - rewrote answer

Comment: Still not working, because the stream must be closed for the data to be sent. and if so the underlying stream will also be closed.